# prime-ng drag/drop in combination with reorder is not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, primeng

I am trying to work on a prime ng table with both drag/drop and reorder enabled.

I can only have one working at a time, but when I enable both functionalities only reorder works.

Looked at the source and looks like the drop event is consumed at the reorder. I have an working example at
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablereorder-dragdrop-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Here if you remove the `[pReorderableRow]="index"`from "Available" table drag drop works into the "Selected" section.

Is there a way to have both reorder and drag/drop working together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to bind this events in the table

(onDragStart)="dragStart(product)" (onDragEnd)="dragEnd()"

here's a sample

```
 <tr pDraggable="products" [pReorderableRow]="index" (onDragStart)="dragStart(product)" (onDragEnd)="dragEnd()">
```

then at the typescript file try adding the function dragStart(product) and dragEnd()

```
  dragStart(data){
    //console.log(data);
  }
  dragEnd(){
    this.drop();
  }
```

trigger the drop() method in the dragend() method.

i tested it from the demo link you provide:
[link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablereorder-dragdrop-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks. That did it.